# Can't unlock the driver's side door with the key

Tags: honda, accord, locks, door

I can't use my key to unlock the door on the driver's side of my Honda Accord 2004 DX. It feels as though something is stuck inside the cylinder.  I tried to clean it with CRC cleaner, but it still feels like something is stuck inside.

I have been going through the passenger-side door to unlock the driver's door from inside. I do not have an electric remote to unlock the doors.

I did some research about replacing the cylinder, but it seemed like if I replaced the door cylinder, I would have to also replaced the ignition cylinder because the cylinder in the door must be matched to ignition.

So, maybe you have better idea to give me instead of replacing the lock cylinder.

Comment: Pull the lock cylinder out of the door. Probably take under an hour. Then disassemble the lock cylinder. If there's something jammed in there then no matter how much CRC or graphite you shove in there on top of it will help.

Answer (score 4):

Try using some graphite lube on the lock cylinder before you give up on it.

If you remove the lock cylinder, disassemble it, and clean it, you may improve it's function.

You should also be able to get the lock cylinder re-keyed at the dealer or a locksmith prior to installation.

Comment: I have a can of this stuff in my garage: http://www.amazon.com/CRC-Graphite-Lube-Aerosol-Black/dp/B007I9XUD0